# why compact operator has countable number of eigenvalues?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

I was reading following proof.[image]

I understand whole proof.But I don’t see where author Proved fact that compact operator has countable number of eigenvalues

Any help will be appreciated thanks a lot

Lemma 5.4 is Reisz Lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: a subset of $\mathbb C$ with at most one limit point is countable.

Comment: Thanks a lot.....